# NSInvalidArgumentException error occurs when calling setDelegate

Tags: ios

I am trying to segue to another screen from a uitableview in iOS5. I have set up a delegate etc. which seems to work (the segue occurs) but I think I need to "set delegate to initialize the data I want to display in the new screen. I get a NSInvalidArgumentException error though when I call it is prepareforsegue.

Here is the code for the uitableview part...

```
#import "iTanksV2ListViewController.h"
#import "tank.h"
#import "tankDetailViewController.h"

@interface iTanksV2ListViewController () 
@property tank *selectedTank;
@end

@implementation iTanksV2ListViewController
@synthesize tanks = _tanks;
@synthesize tankTableView = _tankTableView;
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize selectedTank = _selectedTank;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tankTableView.delegate = self;
    self.tankTableView.dataSource = self;
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Tank Details"])
    {
        UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        myLabel.text = self.selectedTank.tankNumber;
        [segue.destinationViewController setTankNumberLabel:myLabel];
        [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self]; ///this is where it fails!!!
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.selectedTank = [self.tanks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.delegate iTanksListViewController:self choseTank:self.selectedTank];
}
```

and then in the detail view I use the following...

```
-(void)iTanksListViewController:(iTanksV2ListViewController *)sender choseTank:(id)tank
{
    self.tankToShow = tank;
}
```

but this doesn't get called - presumably because i don't successfully call the setdelegate method?!

Comment: So, your `iTanksV2ListViewController` both implements and follows the same protocol. I don't think that's right!

Comment: The console should show a reason for the exception. Typically it's because you're sending a message to an object that doesn't implement that method. What follows NSInvalidArgumentException in the console?

Comment: this is the error reason: '-[tankDetailViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x687b590'

Answer (score 0):

You must not have synthesized your delegate property. Also, make sure that your header file properly has the delegate protocol referenced like

```
@interface TankDetailViewController : UITableViewController <DELEGATEPROTOCOL>
```

Comment: I thought I had... this snippet is from the itanksv2listviewcontroller header:

Comment: You seem to have one class that is named two different things. Your interface and implementation should be the same name. The <iTanksV2ListViewControllerDelegate> goes in the .h file, after the superclass name.  See my example. I also think you need to strongly reference your UITableView outlet.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had... this snippet is from the        itanksv2listviewcontroller header:

```
@interface iTanksV2ListViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *tanks;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tankTableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <iTanksV2ListViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

and this from the m file :

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

and this is what I have put in the detailview m file:

```
@interface tankDetailViewController () <iTanksV2ListViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```